# How to set vue-i18n in a component's property reactively

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I am trying to display some messages or errors depends on an async function result.
When a response's request doesn't include the message property I should use my own.
The problem is that when I use `this.$t("message")` inside the `someMethod` method the `response.message` (data) it isn't reactive. So it won't change after the locale change.

```
<v-alert v-if="response.error || response.message"
  :type="response.error ? 'error' : 'info'">
  {{response.error ? response.error : response.message}}
</v-alert>

export default {
    data() {
      return {
        response: {
          message: "",
          error: ""
        }
      };
    },
    methods: {
      async someMethod() {
        const apiResponse = await sendRequestToAnApi();
        if (apiResponse.message) {
          this.response.message = apiResponse.message;
        } else {
          this.response.message = this.$t("translation")
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I guess I should use computed property to make it work, but I don't have a clue how to mix response object with possible API response.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your API return not only a message but also a code, where the message could be a textual string based on user locale settings, and the code a slug that will always be English, like `users.added` or `project.created`. You can store this code in `response.code` and create a computed property checking this code and returning the correct vue-i18n translation.

```js
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        response: {
          code: "",
          error: ""
        }
      };
    },
    methods: {
      async someMethod() {
        const apiResponse = await sendRequestToAnApi();
        if (apiResponse.code) {
          this.response.code = apiResponse.code;
        } else {
          this.response.code = null
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
        translatedMessage () {
            if (this.response.code === 'users.added') {
              return this.$t('translate')
            }
            return 'unknown code'
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you could also make this work with a textual string coming from the API, but personally I like working with a specific code that is independent from language settings.